# Unable to list folders in GCP using go client library

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-resource-manager

I am going through the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v2) of `cloudresourcemanager` package and trying to build a simple example to list the folders of my GCP project.

The following example however fails

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    cloudresourcemanager "google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v2"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    svc, err := cloudresourcemanager.NewService(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    foldersService := cloudresourcemanager.NewFoldersService(svc)
    fmt.Println(foldersService)
    foldersListCall := foldersService.List()
    resp, err := foldersListCall.Do()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Here")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, fld := range resp.Folders {
        fmt.Println(fld.Name)
    }
}
```

It fails in

```
resp, err := foldersListCall.Do()
```

and the error is

```
googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument., badRequest
```

I have the following environment variables set

```
GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=my-project-id
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/application_default_credentials.json
```

and `gcloud` cli works fine.

Any suggestions what I might be missing?

Comment: Are you sure you enabled programmatic access for your credentials, I know AWS differentiates between cli and programmatic maybe GCP does too? just an idea

Answer (score 2):

The error message is not helpful at all...

The problem is I was not setting the `Parent` parameter in the request, i.e. the `organization` (switching to `v3` helped a bit)

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    cloudresourcemanager "google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v3"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    svc, err := cloudresourcemanager.NewService(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    foldersService := cloudresourcemanager.NewFoldersService(svc)
    foldersListCall := foldersService.List()
    foldersListCall.Parent("organizations/12345678910")
    resp, err := foldersListCall.Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, fld := range resp.Folders {
        fmt.Println(fld.DisplayName)
    }
}
```